# Why is this SVG drop shadow filter clipping the path when it's short?

Tags: svg, svg-filters

So I need some help understanding what's happening with this SVG.

When the path is short and I apply a filter for a drop shadow I get some weird clipping. It doesn't happen when the path is longer.

Short path, with shadow (broken)

[image: Short path, with shadow]

Short path, no shadow

[image: Short path, no shadow]

Longer path, with shadow

[image: Longer path, with shadow]

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 250 250">
  <g transform="translate(125,125)">
    <filter id="dropshadow" x="-125" y="-125" width="250" height="250">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3"></feGaussianBlur>
      <feOffset dx="2" dy="2" result="offsetblur"></feOffset>
      <feComponentTransfer>
        <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.5"></feFuncA>
      </feComponentTransfer>
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode></feMergeNode>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
    <circle
      cx="0"
      cy="0"
      r="58.5"
      stroke="#BBE4D1"
      stroke-width="7px"
      fill="none"
    ></circle>
    <path
      d="M 1.3612572924182083 -64.98574442586495 A 65 65 0 0 0 3.980102097228898e-15 -65"
      stroke="#28B681"
      stroke-width="20px"
      fill="none"
      stroke-linecap="round"
      style="filter: url('#dropshadow')"
    ></path>
    <circle
      cx="0"
      cy="0"
      r="55"
      fill="white"
      style="filter: url('#dropshadow')"
    ></circle>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Plunker here: [link](https://run.plnkr.co/preview/ckt3el1hw00073h6g0cjycwr9/)

Comment: @RobertLongson It's supposed to look like the second image with a drop shadow around the dark green like in the third image. The first image where it's clipped to be a dash is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The default filterUnits is objectBoundingBox
- Since you've not specified filterUnits that's what you'll get
- objectBoundingBox units run from 0 to 1, you might use slightly larger values if your filter goes outside the shape but numbers in the hundreds are clearly a mistake.
- I've corrected your testcase by explicitly specifying the more appropriate userSpaceOnUse units that the values would seem to warrant.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 250 250">
  <g transform="translate(125,125)">
    <filter id="dropshadow" x="-125" y="-125" width="250" height="250" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3"></feGaussianBlur>
      <feOffset dx="2" dy="2" result="offsetblur"></feOffset>
      <feComponentTransfer>
        <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.5"></feFuncA>
      </feComponentTransfer>
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode></feMergeNode>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
    <circle
      cx="0"
      cy="0"
      r="58.5"
      stroke="#BBE4D1"
      stroke-width="7px"
      fill="none"
    ></circle>
    <path
      d="M 1.3612572924182083 -64.98574442586495 A 65 65 0 0 0 3.980102097228898e-15 -65"
      stroke="#28B681"
      stroke-width="20px"
      fill="none"
      stroke-linecap="round"
      style="filter: url('#dropshadow')"
    ></path>
    <circle
      cx="0"
      cy="0"
      r="55"
      fill="white"
      style="filter: url('#dropshadow')"
    ></circle>
  </g>
</svg>
```